# Should I store information about what number record in database has?

Tags: database, database-design

When we look into some Stack Overflow topic, we see in URL a path where we can find a number of the question.

Example: `questions/38726547/title`

We can see the number `38726547` and I'd like to do something similar but my question is - should I store that number in database when saving some data (before the save I'd count all currently added data and increment that by 1)?

Example:

```
question:
  title: "blabla",
  number: 3213
```

or maybe retrieve that information when getting the data from database and counting? In my opinion storing information about number is easier and I wouldn't have to make calculations every time. I wanted to ask you about what's a better practice.

Comment: You're looking for an auto-increment field used as a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number is used to uniquely identify a post, so it should probably be saved in database.

First, you'd want to save it to optimize queries (=searches) on it.

Second, saving it as a primary key in your database will allow you to have other tables (e.g., comments) rely on it with foreign keys.

Third, saving it will allow you the freedom to later change your database. For example, imagine your database is getting too large and you want to purge old deleted topics. If you decide to delete questions `1` and `2`, you'd still want question `3` to point to the same post, regardless of the fact it's now the "first" question in the database.